# Spring databinding with a complex data form (hash map of object with List member)

Tags: java, spring, data-binding

I've been struggling regarding this issue we my system; I am using a complex form with structure:

```
<form:hidden path="details[${detailEntry.key}].locationSites[${locStatus.index}].locationId" />
...
```

then I have form object:

```
class MyForm implements Serializable
{


    private Map<String, DetailVO> details;
      <with getters and setters>

...
}
```

with class DetailVO:

```
class DetailVO
{
...
   private List<LocationSiteVO> locationSites;
  <with getters and setters>
....
}

class LocationSiteVO 
{
...
  private boolean field1;
...
<with getters and setters>
}
```

What happen is there are times (most often) that binding doesn't work specifically in LocationSiteVO.field1 value. Through debugging, I see that it is passed correctly from form (UI) to the controller (meaning binding LocationSiteVO itself) but not on the DetailVO level. 
If anyone has this issue please share how you resolve it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your class DetailVo and LocationSiteVO must also implements `Serializable`.
If after, it still doesn't work, make some `Converter`.

EDIT : Sorry, I think converter aren't useful in your case. It serves to find objects when they are already existing.
By cons you can try to change the path with :

> ${details[detailEntry.key].locationSites[locStatus.index].locationId}

Comment: DetailVO & LocationSiteVO are both Serializable. The problem is on binding LocationSiteVO for DetailVO. Could you elaborate further how converter will resolve that?

Comment: When changing the path: Got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'path' must not be empty

Comment: I finally resolve my problem. It turns out that locationSites is referring only to one object for each details entry. That's why binding is updating only one copy of locationSites.

Comment: Great ! Sorry for not having been able to help you.